# Cronjob for screenshots not working

Tags: command-line, python, cron

I'm trying to schedule a Python script which takes a screenshot every minute and stores it in a folder with that day's date and time.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

path = "/home/user/Desktop/screenshots/"

today = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
time = datetime.now().time().strftime('%H-%M-%S')

os.chdir(path)

try:
    os.mkdir(today)
except:
    pass

os.chdir(today)
os.system("scrot '" + time + ".png'")
```

I'm using a cronjob to run this script every minute.
Line added in crontab file:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Desktop/screenshots/screenshotTake.py
```

This is what gets outputted to the syslogs:

```
Dec 14 11:34:02 username CRON[7668]: (user) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Desktop/screenshots/screenshotTake.py)
Dec 14 11:34:02 username CRON[7667]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Now, the folder gets created alright, but there are no screenshots being saved. I tried logging some text into a log file but again, the logs.txt file got created but no text got written in the file.

I realise that creating a python script and running a simple scrot command might be an overkill but I tried doing this with a shell script and the result was the same. Folder gets created, but no screenshots are saved. Also tried using the pyscreenshot library but same result.

Comment: you can simply do with `* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/scrot "/home/user/Desktop/screenshots/$(date +'\%d-\%m-\%Y \%T').png"`

Comment: But I need to be able to run a python script as I want to be able to do some processing on the screenshots upon being captured. Any idea why it's not taking screenshots when its clearly being run(folders get created)?

Comment: I don't know much python but I believe it's because your script not able to find `scrot` commamd and you need to provide full path of that, maybe something like `os.system("/usr/bin/scrot '" + time + ".png'")`?

Comment: No man, I just tried adding the absolute path in the python script and it still won't work. As I mentioned earlier, I even tried using a python library called pyscreenshot and it still didn't work so I'm pretty sure the issue is not related to the script not being able to find the `scrot` command.

Comment: *scrot* has no way to know what to take a screenhsot of. May be add an env var with a DISPLAY value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same trouble. I find that the problem occurred because we don't say the display that the script should use. In your case I suggest that try put DISPLAY=:0 in the call to the system function.

```
os.system("DISPLAY=:0 scrot '" + time + ".png'")
```

my script is shorter than yours, but have same effects. I save in /bin/take-screenshot

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p $HOME/.logger/$(date +'%Y%m%d')/screenshots
DISPLAY=:0 import -window root $HOME/.logger/$(date +'%Y%m%d')/screenshots/$(date +'%H%M').png
```

and my cronjob is

```
*/5 * * * 1-5 /bin/take-screenshot
```

References: [Scrot: A Command Line Tool to Take Desktop/Server Screenshots Automatically in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/take-screenshots-in-linux-using-scrot/)